# Zorn Lemma, opposite ring and so on........

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, ring-theory, terminology, ideals

I just wanted to confirm some stuff with you regarding ideals, rings and the Zorn Lemma:

Given that

1) A right ideal of any ring automatically is a left ideal of its opposite ring

and

2) that every nonzero ring has a maximal right ideal (by Kuratowski-Zorn’s lemma),

Is it fair to conclude that the maximal right ideal of a nonzero ring is the maximal left ideal of its opposite?

If so, could you illustrate it with the example of a quadratic 2x2 matrix with zero entries in the bottom row?

Comment: Of course that is true that a maximal left ideal in a ring is a maximal right ideal in the opposite ring ; it follows at once from the definition (and Zorn's lemma has nothing to do with this, as the claim is not one about existence of maximal ideals). You can illustrate this with any ring, really, simply because it is true — I don't know what exactly you expect to have illustrated :-/

Comment: WHat is not right in what you wrote is that there is (in general) no such thing as **the** maximal right ideal of a ring, as rings may well have many different maximal right ideals.

Comment: Well, I would like to have this reasoning illustrated with the example of a 2x2 matrix ring. Particularly, with the example where the bottom row is just  mad eup of zero entries. Which would be the maximal right (and left) ideal there?

Comment: Again, there is no such thing as **the** maximal right ideal.

Comment: A left ideal in a ring **is** a right ideal in the opposite ring. Just use the definition to check this. This means that the maximal right ideal you are looking for is simply *the same set* as the left ideal you have.

Comment: Let us say a maximal right ideal, not the maximal. Zorn's lemma states there is always a maximal or top boundary, not necessarily only one.

Comment: As I said, Zorn's lemma has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @javier **a** maximal left ideal in a ring is **a** maximal right ideal in the opposite ring of the ring.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do the following:

- First, show that if $I$ is a left ideal in a ring $R$, then $I$ (the exact same set) is a *right* ideal in the opposite ring $R^{\mathrm{op}}$.
- Next, show that if $I$ is a maximal left ideal in a ring $R$, then $I$ is a maximal right ideal in the opposite ring $R^{\mathrm{op}}$.

It follows from this that the set of maximal left ideals in a ring $R$ is **exactly** the same set as the set of maximal right ideals in the opposite ring $R^{\mathrm{op}}$.

Comment: Then I guess the question is. Which is the opossite ring to the ring of 2x2 matrices with bottom row made of zero entries?

Comment: You should probably edit the question to include your definition ition of "opposite ring", as with the usual one that question simply does not present itself, since it is a construction: one defines the opposite ring of a ring by explicitly constructing it.

Comment: I just would like to know which the opposite ring of the matrix ring of matrices of the form A= a b 0 0 is, where 0 o fill the bottom row.

Comment: It is that set endowed with the same addition and a different multiplication. This is explained, among other places, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_ring).

Comment: Different multiplication is just a consequence of noncommutativity of matrix product.Or are the entries of the matrix allocated in a different order?